# Hurray vs Hooray?

Tags: american-english, british-english, orthography

I've seen two different spellings of this word - which is correct: hurray, or hooray? As in:

> You haven't got any outstanding alerts to action — hurray!

I'm interested specifically in British English, although I'm also curious as to American English.

Comment: They are variant spellings. See also *hurrah*, *huzzah*, *hoorah*, *hooah* (military), etc. Note that they are all attempts to spell out an inarticulate shout, not the other way around. Nobody learns how to cheer out of a book.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That question discusses onomatopoeia, not orthography. The answer goes on to say that the word derives from old European languages. If they're variant spellings, then I guess that should be the answer; but I disagree that the question's a dupe.

Comment: @Danny Beckett: All three answers on the earlier question specifically reference alternate spellings. But quite rightly, none of them identifies any particular version as "correct", since such a position would be Off Topic opinionated pedantry. The top answer does quote Wikipedia: *"hurrah" [is] now generally looked on as the typical British form of cheer*, despite the fact that the question itself uses the orthography "hooray".